# Unable to Start Debugging on the Web Server in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012

Although it is an old question. But I have tried many ways still no clue. I launched Visual Studio 2012 as administrator. My OS is Windows 7 64. IIS Expression shown in  `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IISExpress` is 10.0.175.  But `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp` is 7.5.

[image: 1]

So check the windows IIS feature

[image: 2]

I am sure that the Application pools are started.

[image: 3]

Also I can manually to start the IISExpress by the command:
`powershell "start-process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe' -workingdirectory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\' -windowstyle Hidden"`

Finally I am sure I have run the command `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i` already.

But I still can't start to debug it. So help me please.

**EDIT:**

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Comment: 1) Can you see the virtual directory in IIS? 2) Is the virtual directory started (running)? 3) Can you verify that files have recently been deployed to this directory?

Comment: @Cal279, I can see the virtual directory in IIS. As 2) and 3), how to verify them?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your project's web configuration tab. 1. Right click on your web project and select the "Properties" sub menu item. 2. Select the "Web" List View Item from the list view on the left hand side of the "Web" panel view. If should have a "Servers" section and a "Debuggers" section.

Comment: @lrb, yes. I added the images.

Comment: Do you have an ssl or self signed certificate bound to a domain, if so localhost will not work here. Also, if you have require https checked then http:// will not work here either.

Comment: @lrb, perhaps without ssl bound. The application is working well on my desktop. However it failed on my laptop. Same code.

Comment: The error message indicates that you are not even getting an acknowledgement from IIS. Can you ping that URL from the laptop, or opening it from another client beside vs?

Comment: @lrb. I ping it, but the request could not find host `http://localhost/WebAdminOrion`

Comment: So I understand, is the IIS and VS both installed locally on your laptop? If so then try accessing http://<MACHINE_IP_ADRESS>/WebAdminOrion or http://<WORKSTATION_NAME>/WebAdminOrion

Comment: @lrb, Yes, I think so. do you mean I have to place the IP address into the project url?(The bottom textbox of the last image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is working r I added `IUSRS` group to the project folder.